How can I assemble a relative call to an absolute ptr addr (relative to current rip) using NASM?
I'd like NASM to generate code similar to:
call qword ptr [rip + 0x540]

but can't seem to figure out how to do this.
My current code is:
BITS 64
DEFAULT REL
ORG 0x10000000
abs_addr_of_func_ptr EQU 0x10000600

...

call qword [abs_addr_of_func_ptr]

NASM should have enough info to figure out the current rip at the call, determine the offset to abs_addr_of_func_ptr, and assemble a relative call to the ptr.  But it doesn't seem to want to do this (or at least I haven't found a way to tell it to).  How can I do this?

On FASM, the equivalent code works fine.  Is this a NASM limitation?

Use call qword [rel abs_addr_of_func_ptr]

@Myria That doesn't work on NASM - see OP.  Note that DEFAULT REL makes rel the default.

A workaround:
BITS 64
DEFAULT REL
base_addr EQU 0x10000000
ORG base_addr
abs_addr_of_func_ptr EQU 0x10000600 - base_addr + $$

call [abs_addr_of_func_ptr]

Of course you can remove the base_addr by hardcoding the 0x10000000 if you wish:
BITS 64
DEFAULT REL
ORG 0x10000000
abs_addr_of_func_ptr EQU 0x00000600 + $$

call [abs_addr_of_func_ptr]

